# MySQL Database Optimization for Large Volumes of Repeating Data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a medium sized (100,000 entries) table in MySQL, and I'm trying to optimize it for speed.  The entries contain some data that is transactional in nature, this data will obviously be kept in MySQL.  The remainder of the data will not change over the life of the table nor is it well suited to a table format (i.e. some entries will contain fields that other entries will not, leading to a lot of 'null' values).  Further, much of the data in this second part will repeat, meaning that there may only be 500-1000 unique sets of data which are then paired with the entries in the table.

I'm considering three ways of organizing the data. 
1) Leave all the data in MySQL in table format.
2) Serialize the non-unique data and save that data in a single MySQL field.
3) Serialize the non-unique data and save to a file in the hard disk, referenced by a pointer in the MySQL table.

My question is which format would you recommend and why? Which is going to be fastest, given that I will be running many queries on the database?

Comment: Examples of the data would help a lot.  The most important question is:  "How are you going to use it?"

Comment: Maybe a more simple way of putting it is that each entry in the table is a subclass of a larger type of object. I'm storing all of the variables which are unique to the instance of the subclass in MySQL, because I will need to search and update those variables frequently.  But I will also need read (not write) access to the variables owned by the larger class.

Comment: For example, I have objects A, B, and C. Entries 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are instances of A, B and C, where 1->A, 2->A, 3->B, 4->B and 5->C. What is the best way of storing data which is common to all instances of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing a normalized database.  This is very standard.  You would have the "larger" entity as a single table with an id.

For the more voluminous data, you would have a reference to that `id`, called a foreign key.  This is the structure that relational databases were designed for.  Part of the meaning of "relational" is relationships between entities.

If you only have a few dozen columns, I wouldn't worry about some values being NULL in some rows and others being NULL in other rows.  If you have multiple types of entities, then you can also reflect this in the data structure.

EDIT:

Normalization can have both good and bad effects on performance.  In the case where it reduces the size of the data, then the performance is often better than with denormalized data.  If you have proper index structures, then normalized data structures usually work pretty well.

Comment: Yes, my first instinct was to normalize the data like that, but I'm afraid that this will double my number of queries (once to get the subclass and once to get the master class) and that would seriously degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of indexing engines, such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), do not re-invent the wheel. Sphinx organizes data according to searching / querying options and it is really fast, can handle lots of data. If your database doesnt change often you have to run Sphinx Indexer just once. One of cons of this solution is fact, that Sphinx index files are quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) that will help you.

You can also used [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert) and you can find your answer.